# Memorable 32-bit value as a constant

Tags: c++, c, constants

I am looking for a memorable 32-bit value to be used as a constant. If possible, it should be somewhat funny too.

So far, I have come up with these two:

```
0xcafebabe

0xdeaddad
```

Can you please suggest some other too?

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps you could try posting on funnyhexconstants.com, because this isn't really programming related.

Comment: I like this question, please make it community wiki so it doesn't get closed.

Comment: How is this not programming related?

Comment: @C. Ross: Asker doesn't have rep, why else wouldn't it be? [/s]

Comment: OK, maybe I'm being too serious. Joke posts should be allowed too I guess. I suggest 0xbabe1e55 (babeless) because that's the first thing that came to mind. :( Maybe I should improve my sense of humor. ;)

Comment: This was covered to death in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak

Comment: @Ether: And? The information is useful here.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

A comprehensive list of magic constants is here:

[Hexspeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak)

[Magic Number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming))

And see the links therein.

Answer (score 14):

I wonder, that as a programmer you need to ask. After all it takes a [word-list](http://www.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/) and a one-liner of C++ to find suitable words.

```
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/lambda/lambda.hpp>
#include <boost/lambda/bind.hpp>

int main()
{
    using namespace boost::lambda;
    std::remove_copy_if(
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(std::cin),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "),
        bind(&std::string::size, _1) != 8u
            ||
        bind(
            static_cast<std::string::size_type (std::string::*)(const char*, std::string::size_type) const>(
                &std::string::find_first_not_of
            ),
            _1,
            "abcdefgiost",
            0u
        ) != std::string::npos
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Here are a bunch of [hex words](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/hexwords.html) that you can use to make a constant.

A snippet of some of the words:

```
ba5eba11
bedabb1e
be5077ed
b0a710ad
b01dface
cab005e
ca11ab1e
ca55e77e
deadbea7
defec8
f01dab1e
f005ba11
0ddba11
5ca1ab1e
7e1eca57
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find them yourself easily enough.

```
sed '/[^a-folt]/d' /usr/share/dict/words | tr olt 017 |
awk '{print length, $0}' | sort -n | cut -f2- -d' '
```

Answer (score 2):

The classic is 0xdeadbeef.

Comment: I wouldn't use it, since it's so common as a memory boundary.

Comment: I don't get it: how is 0xDEADBEEF a memory boundary?

Comment: It means that stock memory allocators often use it to mark unallocated blocks already, so its use to mark something else would conflict with that usage.

Answer (score 1):

0xDEADBEEF
0xDEADBABE

...

[Hexspeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another: 0xDEADCAFE  :)

Comment: This one is for dads programming in C! 0xFEEDBABE :)

Answer (score 1):

`0xBADDD00D`, `0xBADDFACE`, `0xCAFEF00D`, `0xBAADCAAB`, `0xBADCAB1E` etc etc

Answer (score 1):

0x00abacab

(Which happened WAY after Peter Gabriel left.)

Answer (score 1):

I like 600df00d

Answer (score 1):

0x0BE5EBEE 0xADEAD60D

Answer (score 1):

I'm a fan of 0xBAADF00D.