# What to choose as a good marker in C?

Tags: c, marker

So, I'm wondering if there's a good marker to choose in C, apart from the common `0xDEADBEEF`or the less appealing (for proper code) `0x0BADA550`.

What's your favorite?
Is there any reason to choose one particular value or another?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Memorable 32-bit value as a constant](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810529/memorable-32-bit-value-as-a-constant)

Comment: For me it wasn't to close, as said in various answers such values are chosen not only for aesthetic and recognizability, but also for some kind of functionality (see the int 3 stuff).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wikipedia has a [whole page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak) on this subject; it provides a lot of examples and famous software in which they are used.

Anyway, if you are working on x86 you should consider following @torak's suggestion, memory filled with `int 3` saved me several times. If you feel creative, you may make it more recognizable and use `CC90CC90`, which translates to alternated `int 3` and `nop`.

Answer (score 4):

The only marker that I can think of that might have more than asthetic value is `0xCCCCCCCC`. If, through some kind of error, it was executed `0xCC` translates to an `INT 3` instruction.

This will work in IA-32 and x86-64. Im not sure if there are equivalents for other architectures.

Comment: @dmckee: Ahh yes. I'll add that in. Thanks!

Comment: I think 0xCCCCCCCC has an additional advantage in that it typically points to kernel virtual memory space, attempting to use such a pointer from userspace would crash the application (which is great for debugging).

Answer (score 3):

Well I always picked `0x80000000`, `0x80000001` incrementing for each new region type to tickle unexpected values with signed integers. Use of these values will be strangely large for unsigned types, largely negative for signed types, and abruptly become positive for any subtractions made (thereby testing for other bugs at the same time). This has another neat side effect, in that various ALU bits will be set such as overflow, which can be detected through use of `-ftrapv` and other compiler flags.

Answer (score 0):

`0xBABECAFE`, `0xBADADD00`, `0xBADBAD00`, `0xFADEFADE`

`0xCAFEBABE` is, I understand, the magic number for Java. The only thing that makes one better than another is how unlikely it is to appear in data or uninitialized memory. So don't use `0x00000000` or all `F`s.

Answer (score 0):

It depends what you're trying to mark.  For example, do you need to distinguish between allocated but uninitialized memory and deallocated memory?  If so, you need different markers for the two.

Answer (score 0):

Everyone has their preference. If everyone on the team uses a different marker, it can help to determine the source of an error. As in:

"DEADBEEF? Oh, this must be from John's code."