# Tools for Dealing with Stack Corruption in c++

Tags: c++, stack, corruption

EDIT: Due to a comment that was right about my example I removed it and turn this into a generic question:

Some times in my projects I come across stack corruption. No matter how much I fight to write code to avoid it, sometimes it is just unavoidable. But when it happens what are the ways to fight it?

I found one macro given by the good fellow in this blog: http://rxwen.blogspot.com/2009/04/detect-stack-corruption.html which reads the ebp register value to detect corruption.

But there are bound to be more sophisticated tools to help with not shooting yourself on the foot. I am programming in Windows using Codeblocks and the gcc compiler. The reason I make this question is to find tools which I can use under my programming environment to help me detect such mistakes and correct them. Any suggestions?

Thanks for any answers and for taking the time to read my question.

Comment: 1. There's no actual code posted. 2. How do you know that there's stack corruption? 3. Why do you think the problem lies where you've indicated? 4. Can you post the contents of the members and constructors of the `artist` class?

Comment: I will rephrase the question. Should not have posted this example. It's not an actual example of corruption in my project, just an example of a corruption I had to deal with in the past, that really took a toll on my nerves.

I will turn this into a generic question about stack corruption and tools for dealing with it.

Comment: <quote>sometimes it is just unavoidable</quote> That's just poppycock. Your best tool to avoid stack corruption is good technique and adherence to best practices.

Comment: You are actually right Martin. I agree with you. The best tool is to use a good technique. Nonetheless I made this post to see if there are any way to get you of a bind sometimes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's far from unclear that you are having *stack* corruption.  But I accept there is some data corruption.

A reasonably effective technique is to add guard fields around the suspect field(s):

```
...
long   namecheck1;
Artist artist;
long   namecheck2;
...
```

Have the constructor initialize these to most anything, but without knowing the nature of the corruption something non-zero seems more satisfying.

```
myclass::myclass() : namecheck1(0x12345678), namcheck2(0x12345678) ...
```

Add a consistency check member function:

```
void myclass::isokay()
{
       if (namecheck1 != namecheck2  ||
           namecheck2 != 0x12345678)
             cerr << "the object is corrupted";
         ... // maybe wait for input, cause core dump, etc.
}
```

Then pepper the code with calls to this, especially near suspicious logic.  If you are comfortable with a debugger, place a breakpoint on the error message.  By unraveling the stack, you can ascertain what the program has done recently and gather clues as to what bit of code is probably writing outside the proper bounds.

Comment: Suggestion: Instead of `0x12345678`, use the more standard `0xBAADF00D`. :)

Comment: I didn't realize there was a standard arbitrary pattern!  :-)

Comment: @wallyk: It's not really arbitrary... "bad food" is [among the terms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexspeak) used to mark hex data like this. :]
@Fred: Haha, I haven't seen that before, nice!!

Comment: There are more: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1810529/memorable-32-bit-value-as-a-constant

Comment: Thank you for your comments and suggestions guys. So that's a standard pattern huh? That's why sometimes while debugging suspicious parts I saw 0xBAADF00D. Thought it was a coincidence. I only knew 0xDEADBEEF :)

Answer (score 1):

Valgrind finds all kinds of memory corruption.

GCC has mudflap (`-fmudflap` and friends) and `-fstack-protector` to catch memory access problems. Other compilers probably do, too.